# Display a specific cell value as a url in the lightning datatable in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I need to have a cell value which has a string value such as "www.google.com" as a URL or a hyperlink. I don't want all the rows for a column to have url , so type = 'url' while defining columns won't work. Link of the playground - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/kPSqiPxWk/5/edit
 Also added the screenshot below.
Here , 3rd row (Image) column - 'Change Value' has text - www.google.com , but it's not clickable. I want this text to be url or hyperlink.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `linkify` type attribute for "text" column type.

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Column', fieldName: 'anyText', type: 'text', typeAttributes: { linkify: true }},
    // other column data
]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I will get rid of the html table

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve recently similar functionality - but not sure if you can have the exact dynamic column format **type** per row you suggested here. 
However, you may either have the `Change Values` column as `text` or `url` where you can style the cells text as you wish using `cellAttributes` to look like a url.

To make it clickable `url` - you can explorer rowActions with type `button` where you can style that dynamically.

Similar example is shared on [answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301343/append-icon-to-column-data/301348?noredirect=1#comment450208_301348) - where you can check on your JS that only when value is a url formal you will invoke this action and when not make it different style.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to change your records dataset and then formatting of columns. I have updated the playground
[Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/kPSqiPxWk/12/edit)

Comment: I don't want all the rows to have URL, rather a specific cell. In the above screenshot, I want 3rd row , to have the url